# Function in react component is not able to get the latest state of an object without using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

The below code is not able to get the latest state of an object in the parent component. Can anyone help me how to get the latest value from the child component and fire the alert without using useEffect?

### App.JSX file code

```
import React, {useState}  from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
const App = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ value: "" });

  const updateState = (newValue) => {
    setState({ value: newValue });
    state.value === '5' && alert('the value is 5');
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ChildComponent updateState={updateState} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### ChildComponent.jsx file Code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.updateState(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

[console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzV4h.png)

The below code is not able to get the latest state of an object in parent component. Can anyone help me how to get the latest value?

Comment: `setState` is async - you can just check `newValue === 5` though!

Comment: @moonwave99 Hello, thank you for your answer. I just created a similar problem I'm facing in my project. So, i can use only state object value. So, is there any way to get the latest value?

Comment: you can use `useEffect(() => state.value === '5' && alert('the value is 5'), [state])` 
it'll be triggered on each state update

Comment: @I-vasilich-I  can i solve this without using useEffect?

Comment: why don't you wanna use useEffect?

Comment: @I-vasilich-I I just created a similar problem that I'm facing in my project. If I useEffect, I need to change the entire code and I need to get the latest state change value.

Comment: well since your updateState function has access to newValue, why don't you use it instead of latest state?

Comment: @SaiChand If you don't mind showing the alert before the component finishes rerendering, you can inline the alert in the component under an if condition. But it does sound like what you want belongs in a `useEffect()` because that will display the alert after the component rerenders.

Comment: if you want to run some side effect(e.g. show alert) on state update - useEffect is the perfect thing for that

Answer (score 2):

You should just use a `useEffect` hook. But if you don't want to do that, you could try calling the alert on the `newValue` instead of `state` like this:

```
const updateState = (newValue) => {
  setState({ value: newValue });
  newValue === '5' && alert('the value is 5');
}
```